# Appsync RDS SQL not returning JSON format

Tags: sql, json, graphql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to get a SQL query to return it's data as JSON using appsync and RDS as data source.
In appsync I'm passing something like this:

```
"statements":  [ "Select * from user WHERE uuid = '001'"]
```

I have as response mapping $ctx.result but I'm getting as a reply

```
{sqlStatementResults=[{records=[[{stringValue=001}, {stringValue=nonemail@none.no}, {stringValue=Nully}, {longValue=62761} ... }
```

I was expecting to get values the same way that is described on the rds helpers doc from amazon https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/rds-helpers-in-util-rds.html where you can see the return from the SQLStatement records is formatted in JSON

```
                    {
                        "stringValue": "Mark Twain"
                    },
                    {
                        "stringValue": "Adventures of Huckleberry Finn"
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so AppSync VTL resolvers are split into 2 parts, the request mapping template and the response mapping template.

After we execute the request mapping template part, the results of it get stored into the context object, the `$ctx`, as `$ctx.result`, so this result key has the result of the previous step, which is the request mapping template execution.

Well, looks like you've got the request mapping template set up correctly, where you execute SQL statements by utilizing the `"statements"` kind of key, that would be executed against your attached data source, which is in that case, the RDS.

Here's the bit, the SQL statements execution results coming back from RDS (called using the Data API when using AppSync) when executing the request mapping template, are in fact these plain results:

```
{sqlStatementResults=[{records=[[{stringValue=001}, {stringValue=nonemail@none.no}, {stringValue=Nully}, {longValue=62761} ... },
```

So, unlike what you'd expected, this `$ctx.result` needs to be parsed back to the right key/value pairs that are configured according to the RDS db schema.

So you would just need to have the response mapping template, parse the results from the request mapping template execution, by simply instead of just returning the `$ctx.result`, you would do this:

```
$util.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0]
```

This would give you back your data, formatted correctly in JSON, with the correct keys.